# How to check if xarray's `DataArray` is `dask.array` without loading the data into memory?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

The following code can check the whether a `DataArray` is  `dask.array` but it will load all data into memory and is thus very slow.

```
import dask.array as da
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature',
         chunks={'lat': 25, 'lon': 25, 'time': -1})

if isinstance(ds.air.data, da.Array):
    print('It is dask.Array')
```

I would like to get the results without loading the whole variable into memory.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file, so it's easier to reproduce?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev My file is over 90GB and too big to upload.  I can observe an obvious surge of memory usage in my task manager when I run `isinstance(ds.some_var.data, da.Array)`.  Nevertheless, I tried to add another sample file to my above code to see if it can ease the reproduction of the problem.

Comment: I tried your example and it works without loading data into memory, as far as I can tell. Can you add output of `print(ds.some_var.data)`?

Comment: If the array is backed by a dask array, `.data` will return a reference without computing. but if it's a lazy-loaded netCDF reader, `.data` will load the data and return a numpy array. so this slow isinstance check behavior is consistent with the data not being a dask array

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev How do you check if data is loaded into memory?

Answer (score 2):

[`xarray.DataArray.chunks`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.chunks.html) will return a tuple of chunksizes if the data is a dask array, or `None` if not. So you can simply test with:

```py
if ds.air.chunks is not None:
    print('It is dask.Array')
```

Comment: I can confirm that this does the trick.